# Why does my JObject to Model Conversion return null?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, model, json.net

I am trying to convert a very simple JObject to a C# model object but for some reason all I get is null.

The object model looks like this

```
public class PerfectFit
{
    public Array Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The Converter is also simple like this

```
public static PerfectFit PerfectFitTopLevelFormat(IQueryable<JObject> unformattedQueryOutput)
{

    //var jongel = unformattedQueryOutput.ToList();


    PerfectFit formattedQueryOuput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PerfectFit>(unformattedQueryOutput.ToList().ToString());


    return formattedQueryOuput;
}
```

And I am calling the converter method like this

```
PerfectFit formattedQueryOutput = ReFormatQueryOutput.PerfectFitTopLevelFormat(queryResultSet);
return Ok(formattedQueryOutput);
```

queryResultSet is retrieved as follows

```
IQueryable<JObject> queryResultSet = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(brandDbInfo.DbName, brandDbInfo.DbCollection), queryElementInfo.SqlStatement, queryOptions);
```

If I simply return queryResultSet.ToList(); I get the following

```
[
    {
        "topLevelCat": "Barn"
    },
    {
        "topLevelCat": "Dam"
    },
    {
        "topLevelCat": "Herr"
    },
    {
        "topLevelCat": "Divided"
    }
]
```

So I know the data is returned fine from my datasource but I am failing to get the conversion into my simple model to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do this`unformattedQueryOutput.ToList().ToString()`, just supply `unformattedQueryOutput`. Or make `Categories` a List instead of an Array. I thiink you can see where I am going, you're trying to DeSerialize to a different type.

Comment: The desserialiser requires a string though or am I missing something ? The final result must be an array so maybe I am a bit confused as to what the conversion is able to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON represents an array of objects where each object contains a string property called `toplevelCat`.  You are trying to deserialize into a single object containing an array called `Categories`.  Since your model doesn't match the JSON, it's not going to work.  Make your model like this:

```
public class PerfectFit
{
    public string TopLevelCat { get; set; } 
}
```

You can deserialize into a `List<PerfectFit>` from your JSON string like this:

```
List<PerfectFit> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PerfectFit>>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/syULkn

If you're starting from an `IQueryable<JObject>` you should be able to do something like this:

```
List<PerfectFit> list = queryResultSet.ToList()
    .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<PerfectFit>()).ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5JS1gX

Comment: ok this works my only problem now is that I cannot go from my IqueryAble<JObject> to the required string needed by the deserializer

Comment: @Matt Douhan I've updated my answer.  Out of curiosity, why are you using `JObject` as an intermediary at all?  Why not just materialize the result of your query directly to your model, i.e. use an `IQueryable<PerfectFit>`?